# Use ffplay to check how much to brighten video before using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video which is a bit dark that I'd like to re-encode and brighten up with ffmpeg.

As a smarter/faster alternative to running ffmpeg in trial/error mode, is there a way to simply use ffplay to find how much to brighten things up, before running ffmpeg with the same settings?

"ffplay -h" returns so much infos that it's hard for newbies :-/

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [simple filtergraphs](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Simple-filtergraphs) easily with `ffplay`.

Example using [colorlevels](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#colorlevels) filter in `ffplay`:

```
ffplay -vf colorlevels=rimax=0.902:gimax=0.902:bimax=0.902 input.mp4
```

Then you can use the same filter in `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf colorlevels=rimax=0.902:gimax=0.902:bimax=0.902 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

This example will [stream copy](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) the audio.

Comment: Thanks for the help. "colorlevels" as used above or even raised to 1 made no difference, but did the job: "-vf lutyuv=y=val*1.5"

Comment: @Gulbahar The values used in my example were probably too subtle (I was lazy and just copied an example from the documentation); you would have needed to lower the values for a greater effect. However, it's good you found an alternative: there are several filters that can brighten the video.